# json object data accessing via index

Tags: c#, json, node.js, unity-game-engine, indexing

I have following json object of array structure.I am trying to retrieve certain elements from array of objects

```
{
"data": [
{
"_id": "5b62dc6ebef986403db8aafd",
"name": "smitha vijaya",
"designation": "account management",
"projects": {
"project1": "description1",
"project2": "description2"
},
"age": "27"
},
{
"_id": "5b62dd17bef986403db8ab90",
"name": "JIKKU VARGHESE",
"designation": "SUPERVISING OPERATIONS MANAGER",
"projects": {
"project1": "description1",
"project2": "description2"
},
"age": "27"
},
{
"_id": "5b62dd76bef986403db8abe3",
"name": "SUJEETH  NAIR",
"designation": "MENA AMS",
"projects": {
"project1": "description1",
"project2": "description2"
},
"age": "30"
},
{
"_id": "5b62ddb1bef986403db8ac13",
"name": "GIRISH   KN",
"designation": "MENA  AMS",
"projects": {
"project1": "description1",
"project2": "description2"
},
"age": "27"
}
]
}
```

I am using following c# code to extract ist name (smitha)

```
JsonData jsonvale = JsonMapper.ToObject( jsonString);
         Name = jsonvale["data"][0]["name"].ToString();
print (name);
```

how can i acces other elements like name jikku and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate it over your json array like following:

```
JsonData jsonvale = JsonMapper.ToObject( jsonString);
for (var i=0; i<jsonvale.length; i++){
    print(jsonvale["data"][i]["name"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I am getting an errror json data doesnot contain a definition for length.

Comment: can i access the other elements by indexing like ist name

Comment: samae error is coming  json data doesnot contain a definition for length and no extension method length accepting a first argument of type json data could be found(are you missing an assembly reference or using directive)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate using a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonvale.length; i++) {
    JsonData jsonvale = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonString);
    Name = jsonvale["data"][i]["name"].ToString();
    print(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just deserialize this json in List() and then you can access all data from this list without loops, and when you do not need this list anymore, you can destroy it.  See this example https://github.com/IonCojucovschi/JsonDeserializeGenericForm